# sql_variant read using Entity Framework as an object cannot be cast to its actual type

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a large database that I use Entity Framework to connect to. One of these tables has a column of type `sql_variant`, which Entities doesn't support, so I read it using some raw SQL.

```
string MinWeight = CEntity.Database.SqlQuery<string>(MinQuery).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which worked fine.. until a data problem meant that 1% of the records we cared about stored a numeric in that sql_variant, and the above gave me a cast exception. I tested out this and it read the value in fine

```
double MinWeightdouble = CEntity.Database.SqlQuery<double>(MinQuery).FirstOrDefault();
```

But since I need to handle both double (SQL numeric) and string, I tried

```
object MinWeightVariant = CEntity.Database.SqlQuery<object>(MinQuery).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which I assumed I could easily cast to string or double, but that's not the case. Attempting to cast to a double gives me an error about how I can't cast an object to a double, `MinWeightVariant.GetType()` just gives me System.Object. It appears that, while it knows deep down in the sql read that it's numeric, that data gets lost when it's assigned to an object. Any idea how to fix this in a sensible way?

Comment: I don't have time to set up a test environment for this, but what about `Convert.ToDouble(minWeightVariant)`? [There's also some code here that looks related, but doesn't solve your exact issue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137509/Reading-sql-variant-in-Entity-Framework).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this would help you but in T-SQL world you could always "interrogate" sql_variant value to find out about underlying data type via **SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms178550.aspx.
Would you like to try this approach by passing Value as well as Base Type to EF?

Comment: For read only, a view can be created with a separate column for each expected datatype and fill it when the sql_variant_property(BaseType) property is compatible.  Then import the view into EF.